# Java program : Leap Year Calculator

Tags: java, leap-year

I have written a program to calculate a leap year. The second part is where i have to print the number of years to the next leap year if the year is not a leap year.
For 2097 ,the output shows 3 years untill next leap but its supposed to be 7 years. I think i have made a mistake with the code in the last line. Please help me out.
This is my code so far.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int year = 2093;


    if((year%4==0) && year%100!=0){           
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
         }
    else if ((year%4==0) && (year%100==0)&&         (year%400==0)) { 
        System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year");
        System.out.println(4-(year%4)  + " years untill next leap year");
    }
```

Comment: If you can explain *why* the next leap year after 2097 is in 7 years, you'll be a good way to figuring out how to code it.

Comment: Leap years happen every 4 years, so its impossible for the next one to be more than 3 years away?

Comment: `4 - (2097 % 4)` is `3` to me.

Comment: Yeah. But 2100 is not a leap year because it does not fulfill the above conditions. So the next leap year is supposed to be 2104.

Answer (score 1):

Your leap year determination appears correct.  However, you are calculating the next leap year based on the incorrect "every 4 years is a leap year" rule with this expression:

```
4-(year%4)
```

You can find the next leap year by the following:

1. Start with the next year after `year`.  Use the same logic you have already written to determine if it's a leap year.
2. If it's not, keep incrementing that "next year" value until you do find a leap year.

You will find it useful to place your `if` logic in a separate method to avoid the repetition of code and logic.

Answer (score 1):

Main code:

```
int year = 2093;
if (isLeapYear(year) {
    System.out.println(year + " is a leap year");
} else {
    int moreYears = nextLeapYear(year) - year;
    System.out.println(moreYears + " more years until next leap year");
}
```

[Check if a year is a leap year:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm)

```
public boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{   
    if (year % 4 != 0)
        return false;
    else if (year % 100 != 0)
        return true;
    else if (year % 400 != 0)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

Get next leap year:

```
public int nextLeapYear(int year)
{
    while( !isLearpYear(year) )
        year++;

    return year;
}
```

Comment: the "case" variant looks ugly and is less efficient than the original `isLeapYear()` method. I would suggest to revert this edit.